# How to access group name in Django choices?

Tags: python, django

I use nested tuples to organize and display choices in the admin section, and I would like to access the first element of the chosen tuple. In the example below, assuming the selected media is `vinyl` I would like get `Audio`. How can I do that ?

```
from django.db import models

class Student(models.Model):

    MEDIA_CHOICES = [
        ('Audio', (
                ('vinyl', 'Vinyl'),
                ('cd', 'CD'),
            )
        ),
        ('Video', (
                ('vhs', 'VHS Tape'),
                ('dvd', 'DVD'),
            )
        ),
        ('unknown', 'Unknown'),
    ]
    media = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=MEDIA_CHOICES)
```

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, there is no function for that, so you will need to write your own:

```
from django.db import models
from operator import itemgetter


class Student(models.Model):

    MEDIA_CHOICES = [
        (
            'Audio',
            (
                ('vinyl', 'Vinyl'),
                ('cd', 'CD'),
            ),
        ),
        (
            'Video',
            (
                ('vhs', 'VHS Tape'),
                ('dvd', 'DVD'),
            ),
        ),
        (
            None,
            (('unknown', 'Unknown'),)
        ),
    ]
    media = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=MEDIA_CHOICES)

    @property
    def media_group(self):
        media = self.media
        return next(
            (
                g
                for g, vs in self.MEDIA_CHOICES
                if media in map(itemgetter(0), vs)
            ),
            None,
        )
```

This will return `None` in case the group can not be found, or if the group is `None` (see edits to the `MEDIA_CHOICES`.

Comment: what is a reason to do `media = self.media`?

Comment: @rzlvmp: just elegancy, this avoids fetching `self.media` for each group in `MEDIA_CHOICES`.

Comment: Interesting... `media` and `self.media` are both `str` objects in memory. Not sure if fetching of `media` will be noticeably faster than `self.media` even for big tuples

Comment: @rzlvmp: it is not the fact that the logic to fetch `self.media` is complex. But a "get attribute" still requires some work, although, I agree, very minimal. So `x.y` is less efficient than using a variable `y` directly.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. Does it work also if a choice is present in multiple groups ?

Comment: Probably I wasn't correct... `self.mdeia` is an instance of `models.CharField` and should return `str` value dynamically by using getter. If `media` is a returned `str` value of `self.media` instance it will be more effective to get it once before loop

Comment: @rzlvmp: no, it makes use of `__get__` and `__set__` logic to do that in a transparent manner, so `self.media` is *not* a `CharField`, it is a `str`ing. `Student.media` is indeed a `CharField`, but Django thus does some meta-programming such that `self.media` will be the value stored for that field for that model object.

Comment: @Florent: then it will pick the first group. But normally that does not make sense, since the field will simply store `vinyl`, not its group, so if you save the record, then the picked group is "gone".

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem true, I noticed that Django always select the first group when a choice is present in several groups. I will customize choices, thanks again